# fast intersection, complement and union of tab-delimited text files?

Tags: shell, unix, text, command-line, csv

Can someone recommend a fast unix-based utility (ideally written in C) for getting efficient, streaming intersection/union of tab-delimited text files?  For example, allow queries such as "give me the all the entries that in file A that have a column value K that does not appear in any column K of file B".

e.g., if file A is:

```
bob sally sue
bob mary john
```

and file B is:

```
john sally sue
foo bar quux
```

then complement of file A relative to B on column 2 would return "bob mary john", since that's the only in file B that has a value in column 2 that does not appear in file B.

I'd prefer not to use a database, but would like a command line based utility. Is awk the answer or is there something simpler?
thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it were only for that particularly query, I'd probably go with awk, hash B's 2. columns and filter A based on the hash.